# line break in textarea without displaying HTML tags

Tags: php, html

I am using this HTML/PHP Code

```
<textarea name="ticket_update" id="ticket_update" cols="70" rows="2"><?php echo 'Ticket '.$ticket["ticketnumber"].'\n'.$result["notes"]; ?></textarea>
```

I have tried using `\n` `\n\r` and `<br />` but it is displaying the HTML tags in the textarea.

how can i stop them displaying?

Comment: use double quotes and try.. single quote will not parse the new line character..

Comment: @charlie See my answer use  html_entity_decode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&#10;` as a line break.

Like this :

```
<textarea name="ticket_update" id="ticket_update" cols="70" rows="2"><?php echo 'Ticket '.$ticket["ticketnumber"].'&#10;'.$result["notes"]; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Because you didnt just take that from my answer... Read other answers before posting. (pretty sure you just took that from me)

Answer (score 0):

use `"\n"`  as opposed to `'\n'` to display a line break;

To remove HTML tags from the contents, use `strip_tags()` function;

a complete example would look like this:

```
<textarea name="ticket_update" id="ticket_update" cols="70" rows="2">
      <?php echo strip_tags('Ticket '.$ticket["ticketnumber"]."\n".$result["notes"]); ?> 
</textarea>
```

Also, it looks like there might be some PHP notices or warnings occuring in your code; If your `$ticket` array does not have `ticketnumber` key, you will get error message including some HTML tags; You should either check for the presence of each key you use with `array_key_exists`, or silence errors with `@` like this:

`echo @strip_tags('Ticket '.$ticket["ticketnumber"]."\n".$result["notes"]);`

Answer (score 0):

A textarea cannot have any child elements. If you don't want error recovery to try to render tags, then don't put tags in the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<textarea name="ticket_update" id="ticket_update" cols="70" rows="2"><?php echo 'Ticket: '.$ticket["ticketnumber"].'&#10;'.$result["notes"]; ?> </textarea>

&#13;&#10; = line break
```

`&#10;` = Line Feed and `&#13;` = Carriage Return

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/PeBpa/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
<?php
$ticket = '50';
$nodes = 'sample'    
?>

<textarea name="ticket_update" id="ticket_update" cols="70" rows="2"><?php echo 'Ticket '.$ticket.html_entity_decode("\n").$nodes; ?></textarea>
```

**[Demo Output](http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/rxc-6zh)**